# Can't get Google Visualization API to work. It throws an error

Tags: google-visualization

Here's my code and the error I get:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Views');
data.addColumn('number', 'Winks');
data.addRows([
                  [new Date('2012-25-07'), 1, null],
                  [new Date('2012-23-07'), 1, null],
                  [new Date('2012-21-07'), 1, null],
                  [new Date('2012-19-07'), 1, null],
                  [new Date('2012-18-07'), 1, null],
                  [new Date('2012-17-07'), 1, null],
                  [new Date('2012-16-07'), 1, null],
                  [new Date('2012-15-07'), 1, null],
                  [new Date('2012-14-07'), 1, null],
                ]);

var formatter_short = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'short'});
formatter_short.format(data, 0);

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data);
```

> Error: Problem parsing
>   d="Mnull,162.5Lnull,101Lnull,101Lnull,101Lnull,101Lnull,101Lnull,101Lnull,101Lnull,101Lnull,101"

Comment: hmm... use this format: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#area_chart

Answer (score -1):

Your 3rd col is a number type so you can't put "null" as value try putting '0' inste